# Filtering a dataframe based on the conditional count on a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as given below

`df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,4,1,2,2,3,1,3,3,4], 'b':[3,2,5,6,4,5,5,6,4,4,2,6,1], 'c':[4,4,5,4,3,5,3,3,3,2,4,3,5]})`

```
df
    a  b  c
0   1  3  4
1   2  2  4
2   3  5  5
3   4  6  4
4   4  4  3
5   1  5  5
6   2  5  3
7   2  6  3
8   3  4  3
9   1  4  2
10  3  2  4
11  3  6  3
12  4  1  5
```

I want to filter the dataframe to return a data frame containing entries such that for each unique value of the column 'a', the count for column 'c' taking value greater than 3 should be greater than or equal to 2.

In the above example, I want my output dataframe to be

```
0  1 3 4
2  3 5 5 
3  4 6 4
4  4 4 3
5  1 5 5
8  3 4 3
9  1 4 2
10  3 5 4
11  3 6 3
12  4 4 5
```

Since the column 'a' with value 2 such that 'c' > 3 is less than 2. I should drop all those such rows. The other rows appear as 'a' = 1 has corresponding count('c' >3) >= 2 and 'a' = 3 has corresponding count('c' > 3) >= 2 and 'a' = 4 has count('c' >3) >= 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare column `c` for greater values by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html), then count values by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and `sum` (`True`s values are processing like `1`) and last filter by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) for greater or equal in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['c'].gt(3).groupby(df['a']).transform('sum').ge(2)]
print (df)
    a  b  c
0   1  3  4
2   3  5  5
3   4  6  4
4   4  4  3
5   1  5  5
8   3  4  3
9   1  4  2
10  3  2  4
11  3  6  3
12  4  1  5
```